# I am getting error while running this part of the code. tried some of the existing solutions, none of them helped

Tags: python, image-recognition

```
for face_location in face_locations:
top , right, bottom , left = face_location
print("A face is located at the pixel locations Top: {} , Right:{} , Left: {} , Bottom: {}.")

   **** I always get this error:****

 File "<ipython-input-55-23558b69803e>", line 1
for face_location in face_locations:
```

^SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: When any error pops up, the actual error is usually the line above or the line below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you forgot to use a tab after the for loop?
instead of

```
for face_location in face_locations:
top , right, bottom , left = face_location
```

do

```
for face_location in face_locations:
    top , right, bottom , left = face_location
```